# How to prove algebraically that $\ln|\tan(\frac{x}2)| = \sin(x)\tan(x) $?

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus

I solved the following integral in two ways.

$$ I = \int \frac1{\sin(x)} dx$$

---

### Solution 1

$I_1 = \int \frac1{\sin(x)}dx = \int \frac1{2\sin(\frac{x}2)\cos(\frac{x}2)} dx = \int \frac{\frac1{\cos^2(\frac{x}2)}}{2sin(\frac{x}2)\cos(\frac{x}2)} dx = \int \frac{\tan'(\frac{x}2)}{\tan(\frac{x}2)} dx = \ln|\tan(\frac{x}2)| + c_1 \iff $

$$ \boxed{I_1= \ln|\tan(\frac{x}2)| + c_1} $$

---

### Solution 2

$I_2 = \int \frac1{\sin(x)}dx = \int \sin(x) \tan'(x) dx =  \sin(x) \tan(x) -  \int \cos(x) \tan(x) dx =  \\\sin(x) \tan(x) + \int \sin'(x) \tan(x) dx =  2\sin(x)\tan(x) - \int \frac1{\sin(x)}dx =  2\sin(x)\tan(x) - I_2 \iff \\ 
2I = \frac12\sin(x)\tan(x) + c_2 \iff$ $$\boxed{I_2 = \sin(x)\tan(x) + c_2}$$

---

But $I = I_1 = I_2 \iff \ln|tan(\frac{x}2)| +c_1 = \sin(x)\tan(x) + c_2$

I plotted the results and it is clear that their graphs are different ($\ln|tan(\frac{x}2)| $ in blue):

[image]

Calculus proves that these functions are equal, but I am having a hard time proving algebreically.

So, how to prove that $\ln|tan(\frac{x}2)| = \sin(x)\tan(x) $? And why are the plots different?

Comment: Your solution 2 is wrong. $\dfrac {d}{dx}\tan x = \sec^2 x = \dfrac 1 {\cos^2x}$.

Comment: Indeed... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few corrections:

- For solution $1$ it should be $$\int \frac1{2\sin(\frac{x}2)\cos(\frac{x}2)} dx = \int \frac{\frac1{\cos^2(\frac{x}2)}}{2\frac{sin(\frac{x}2)}{\cos(\frac{x}2)}} dx $$
- For solution $2$ since $\tan'(x)=\frac{1}{\cos^{2}(x)}$ then you should have $\sin(x)\tan'(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos^{2}(x).}$

Substituting $u=\csc(x)+\cot(x)$ you can also show that $$\int\frac{1}{\sin(x)}dx=-\ln|\csc(x)+\cot(x)|+c$$
$$=-\ln|\frac{\cos(x)+1}{\sin(x)}|+c=\ln|\tan{\frac{x}{2}}|+c.$$

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have made an error in one/both of your integrals as the two are not the same:
$$f(x)=\ln|\tan(x/2)|$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{\sec^2(x/2)}{2\tan(x/2)}=\frac{\sin(x)}{2(1+\cos(x))}+\frac{\csc(x)+\cot(x)}{2}$$
$$g(x)=\sin(x)\tan(x)=\frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos(x)}$$
$$g'(x)=\frac{2\sin(x)\cos^2(x)+\sin^3(x)}{\cos^2(x)}=2\sin(x)+\sin(x)\tan^2(x)$$
now notice that $f'(x)\ne g'(x)$